# Use prepopulated SQLite database in android while using exisntent android API

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I wan't to use database file, that I've created on my computer.

While [this](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) is working, I'm considering that as a bad workaround, as it's not using existent API, while creating its own api.

I want to be able to use getWritableDataBase(), onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) and onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) methods.

So, that's what I did and it's not working for some reason. I thought that if I would rewrite existent database it would work, but when querying I'm getting table not exists exception.

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    File f = new File(db.getPath());
    try {
        InputStream is = context.getResources().getAssets().open("words1.db");
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos.write(buffer);
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

So how could I use prepopulated database, while using existent api?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you replace your code with `SQLiteAssetHelper`, which is tested and debugged code for packaging a database with an app: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: Hey, this is totally working! I am so glad, that you've helped me =)
If you want, you can answer the question, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to pre-package a database with your application is to use [Jeff Gilfelt's `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). While it does require you to add a small JAR to your project, his code is tested and debugged, and it requires very little additional code on your part.

[Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsAssets) demonstrating the use of `SQLiteAssetHelper`.